# Django Rest serializer raises lazy translation error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is a simplified snapshot of my code.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
from rest_framework import status, renderers, serializers
```

In ShopUser model, email field is defined as:
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShopUser
        fields = ('email',)

class RemoveUser(UpdateAPIView):
    model = ShopUser
    permission_classes = (IsRegisteredShopUser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        except Exception as e:
            log(...)
```

.isValid() always raises the exception below.

```
`{'email': [<django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff2e0db8ef0>]}`. More error details: `{'email': [<django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff2e0db8ef0>]}`. ShopUser `ted@ross.com` submitted these data `<QueryDict: {'email': ['test@test.com']}>`
```

But instead if use the following serializer, everything runs smoothly

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializer.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: A little bit late to the party, but if someone comes up with the same issue, there is an answer for this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501644/what-is-a-django-utils-functional-proxy-object-and-what-it-helps-with/24925195#24925195)